# как передать свойство

Tags: c#, framework

как тут передать свойство ??

```
this.panel2.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel2_MouseClick,123);

private void panel2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e,int ids)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Message");
}
```

Comment: Если у вас обработчик события имеет доп. параметры, то вам нужно получить `sender` и `args` и их вручную передать в нужный метод (это нечто на подобие такого: `+= (s, e) => SomeMethod(s, e, 123)`, где 123 - это ваше доп. параметр. Но мне не понятно, зачем вы делаете `new MouseEventHandler()`?

Comment: а можно по другому ?

Comment: При подписи на событие, наверно нет. Но лично я вообще не пойму, зачем вы передаете туда еще параметры, это редко когда используется в проектах. Распишите наверно подробней свою задачу (кнопка "править" под вопросом) и тогда может вам дадут грамотное решение.